# What does "Any time now" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Black Widow (2021)*, Yelena and Natasha are escaping from Black Widows, so
Yelena steal a guy's car

> Natasha: You can't just steal a guy's car.
>
> Yelena: So you want me to chase him down and un-steal it?

Yelena sitting in the car, Natasha damages a guy's car by reversing it:

> Yelena: Okay. **Any time now**, please.
>
> Natasha: Shut up.

What does "Any time now" mean?

Comment: Far too little context given.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I added extra context.

Comment: ***Any time now = As soon as you're ready / As soon as possible***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiom.  It is used in answer to a "when" question to mean "really as soon as possible", with the suggestion of some annoyance, because the thing is already late.

> Do you want some coffee.
>
> Yes, I've been waiting for 45 minutes already.
>
> When would you like it?
>
> Any time now!

It sounds like Yelena is telling Natasha that "any time now" would be a good time stop reversing. It is sarcastic, which is why Natasha tells her to "shut up"

Comment: Hello James K, does your answer stand despite **changes** to the question?

Comment: yes...........................